# Execution of mingw32.exe failed in codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks

I have installed CodeBlocks.
Now I am trying to execute my 1st C program. But it gives me the above mentioned error.
I have checked Settings->Compiler. The GNU GCC Comppiler is selected. Also in the Toolchains executables tab, the mingw32 folder is selected.